# Finding if any orbit is closed or not

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, orbital-motion

I came across a problem where I was supposed to answer whether the path was bounded or unbounded and closed or open. I know how to find if it is bounded or not, which can be shown by taking the effective potential diagram vs position coordinate graph and taking points of intersection with the line of total energy. How to find if the orbit is closed or open?
Also, if the orbit is closed, will it always be periodic?

Answer (score 4):

You can immediately see if your problem has closed and/or open orbits from the level curves of your Hamiltonian, provided your system *is* Hamiltonian. If it isn't, you'll need to evaluate your solutions (probably using numeric methods) to see if $\text{solution}(t+\alpha)=\text{solution}(t)$, which is the definition of a closed orbit. Closed and periodic are two names for the same thing, and all closed orbits are bounded.

As an example, take the Simple Harmonic Oscillator. The Hamiltonian is a set of ellipses, which means all orbits are closed. As another example take the Hamiltonian to be

$$H = \frac{p^2}{2} -  \frac{q^2}{2} -  \frac{q^3}{3} \, .$$

Its level curves around the origin are

[image]

You can clearly see a region around $(-1,0)$ that has periodic orbits, together with an homoclinic orbit and many other unbounded, non-periodic trajectories. If your system is non-Hamiltonian, [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/how-to-find-the-period-of-an-arbitrary-mathematical-function) in Mathematica.SA might help.

**Edit:** If you're talking about the two body problem, then every bounded orbit is periodic. This can be seen by solving the equations of motion explicitly, but not by analysing the effective potential. Remember that in the two body problem all orbits are either parabolas or ellipses (or straight lines, which are parabolas of infinite focus). This should clear your view.

Comment: I don't know what Hamiltonian is. ;-;

Comment: Total energy... In a way.

Comment: Suppose, I am talking about the orbit of the earth around the sun. Everyone knows the effective potential curve. I can prove that the orbit is bounded since total energy is negative. How do I prove that the orbit is closed?

Comment: Ehh, I didn't know your background before answering. Could you provide it? Do you know calculus?

Comment: I know basic high school level calculus - Integration and Differentiation. Definitely not Hamiltonian ;-;

Comment: If you consider your system to be composed of only the Sun and the Earth, then Earth's orbit is an ellipse and you can be quite sure it is both closed and periodic. If you're considering your system to be larger, that is, including the Moon or any other astral bodies, then this is your first encounter with a problem called "the three body problem", which was revolutionary in the history of Physics and has no analytical solution... That is, you can't say anything.

Comment: I'm a first year student in a university. Now, I have to tell that using the graph of the effective potential. I know earth moves in an ellipse. I was giving an example. I'm talking about two body systems only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44756/discussion-between-quark-and-quantumbrick).